# Infinite sum for e^x converges to an incorrect value

Tags: c++, math

I'm trying to implement a way to calculate e^x without using factorials. I did this by getting the ratio between every two consecutive terms and calculate the next term by multiplying that ratio with the last term. All of that is added to the result sum until the term is small enough to not matter.

This works, for small values of x. For *"extreme"* values of x, this breaks for some reason. I tried -50, which should print 1.9287498e-22 (in fixed-form).
What I get instead is -56676.4235303065 in GNU GCC and 2041.8329628977 in VC++. Both are beyond wrong. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(10) ;
    cout << "Enter x: " << endl;
    cin >> x;
    double sum = 0;
    long long i = 0;
    double term = 1;
    do
    {
        sum += term;
        term *= (x / (++i));
    } while (fabs(term) > 1e-10);
    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

And here are my questions: What is the problem that causes this mistake to appear *only* for big values of x, how can I fix this mistake?, why do GNU GCC and VC++2017 get completely different answers?

Comment: Have the curiosity of displaying the values of all terms. This should help you understand.

Comment: What versions of GCC and VC are you using?

Comment: FWIW I tried it in GCC at my end and got output of `2041.8329628977` when `x = -50`.

Comment: @Dai I'm using the compiler in Code::Blocks, I'm not aware how to know which specific version it is or how to change it.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I did that, and that gives me a suspision that it is a problem with the double accuracy. But shouldn't an accuracy problem give out a somehow close answer regardless?

Comment: it was leftover from the method I used to do as a condition for the end of the loop. Removed.

Comment: @Megadardery: C++ has a lot of unspecified behaviors.

Comment: Odds are good that all you need to do to get the gcc version is open a command prompt, type `gcc -v`, and hit enter.

Comment: Or even better, `g++ --version`.

Comment: On gcc 4.8.3 I get 2041.8329... as well. Printing the intermediary values of `term` it can be clearly seen that the terms get too big too fast and exceed the amount of bits available for representation, becoming approximations. Changing the type from double to float and changing the term computation to distinct orders (`term *= x; term /= ++i;`, `term /= ++i; term *= x;` and yours `term *= (x/++i);` also yield different results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The largest term in this summation is ~10 orders of magnitude greater than the precision of `double`: `~ 2.92e+20` compared to the `double`'s 13 s.f. or so. The error margins in these terms are themselves ~30 orders greater than your summation result.

Thus, it is no surprise that your series does not converge correctly, since successive terms (opposite sign) may not cancel by the theoretical amount. Even by using some numerical tricks, such as Kahan-Neumaier summation and sorting the terms before adding, the result could still only be reduced to `~6000`. Note that this would not occur for positive `x` since successive terms need not cancel.

One way to overcome this would be to impose a small lower limit on `x`, and use exponentiation-by-squaring to scale up to the correct value of `x`.

UPDATE: implementation of the method above:

```
// integer exponentiation by squaring (won't explain here)
double pow_square(double x, unsigned a)
{
   double r = 1.0;
   while (a > 0)
   {
      if (a % 2 == 1)
      {
         a--;
         r *= x;
      }
      a /= 2;
      x *= x;
   }
   return r;
}

// original method
double exp_original(double x, double e)
{
   double sum = 0.0;
   unsigned i = 0;
   double term = 1.0;
   do
   {
      sum += term;
      term *= (x / (++i));
   } while (fabs(term) > e);
   return sum;
}

// new adaptive method
double exp_new(double x, double e)
{
   static const double min_X = -3;

   // if within limit, simply use original function
   if (x >= min_X)
      return exp_original(x, e);

   // compute smallest possible scaling coefficient
   unsigned s = (unsigned)(x / (-min_X) + 0.5);
   double p = exp_original(x / s, e);
   return pow_square(p, s);
}
```

Tests for a range of large `x` values confirm the the new method deals with extremal (*negative*) cases much better:

```
x    | exp (C-library)    exp_original       exp_new
-------------------------------------------------------------
-10  | 4.53999297625e-05  4.53998989141e-05  4.53999299001e-05
-30  | 9.35762296884e-14  6.10299992426e-06  9.35762292245e-14
-50  | 1.92874984796e-22  2041.8329629       1.92874983803e-22
-60  | 8.7565107627e-27   722745700.93       8.75651067587e-27
-80  | 1.80485138785e-35  2.45082011705e+17  1.80485137011e-35
-100 | 3.72007597602e-44  8.1446527451e+25   3.72007589785e-44
-150 | 7.17509597316e-66  -9.14622659954e+47 7.1750957953e-66
-200 | 1.38389652674e-87  7.69097143891e+69  1.38389648613e-87
```